# why does the pro_lighting_studio doesn't work in eevee?

Tags: python, add-on, eevee-render-engine

I installed pro_lighting_studio in Cycles in Blender 2.79 but
I was trying to install the pro_lighting_studio in Blender EEVEE 2.80 but when I install the add-on it says

> error (see console)

[image]

and i don't understand what it means so i opened the scripts and this what it says[image]

and the addon doesn't appear in the property panel

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. 2.8 has not yet been officially released, and Pro Lighting Studio is a third party add-on not maintained by the Blender Foundation. I'm sure fixes will be on the way once 2.8 is released: Blender Guru is normally pretty good about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addon is incompatible with Blender 2.8 due to changes to Blender's API. It will need to be updated in order to work, either by the developer or by yourself.

Comment: if i want to update it by myself how to do it?